# Accessing information from object in array list

Tags: object, arraylist

I have two classes, Teachers and Pupils. In the teacher class there is an array list of pupils (containing instances of pupil).
I'd like to do something like:
System.out.println(pupils.get(1).getName())
where getName is a method from the pupil class. However, pupils.get(1) does not seem to act as a pupil and won't let me call this method, any help with why? Or how I can get it to?
Thanks!

I think this is the relevant code:
From the Pupil class:

```
public Pupil(String f, String s){
    forename = f;
    surname = s;
}

public String getName() {
    return forename + surname;
}
```

From the Teacher class:

```
protected ObjectArrayList pupils= new ObjectArrayList();

public void addPupil(Pupil p){
    pupils.add(p);  
}

public void printName() {
    System.out.println(pupils.get(0).getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast the object,

```
Pupil pupil=(Pupil)pupils.get(0).getName();
```

as in,

```
System.out.println(pupil.getName());
```

Comment: It still says it can't find the method :/

Comment: Have you imported the Pupil class in Teacher class?

Comment: ah wait, it worked if I assigned it as a pupil before putting it in the println method, thanks!